# regex callback function only executes once

Tags: javascript, regex, callback

So I am searching a string for {x} where x is some number between 1-9 and my regexp finds the first occurrence and runs the callback function but this is only called on the first found instance. For example, {2}Some{3}String will return the replacement value x number of times depending on the integer between the brackets so the function is returning `&#09;&#09;Some{3}` when I would like it to return `&#09;&#09;Some&#09;&#09;&#09;String`.

I don't know very much regexp but is there something that I need to add in-order to have the callback function executed on all matched occurrences?

Here's the code

```
var string = "{2}Some{3}String";

function replaceWithTabs(propertyName) {  
  var regExp = new RegExp('\{[1-9]\}');
  function addTabs(match) { 

    var string = '',
        i = 0,
        length = match.substring(1,2);

    for(i; i < length; i++) {
        string += "&#09;";
    }
    return string;  
}  return propertyName.replace(regExp, addTabs);  }
```

Comment: You didn't set global flag. When using RegExp object, needs a second argument 'g':  RegExp('\{[1-9]\}',  'g');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this `RegExp` literal instead:

```
var regExp = /{[1-9]}/g;
```

`{` or `}` is not a special symbol in `Regular Expression` so you can avoid slashes. `g` flag of RegExp means `global match`,without that you will only replace first match,but not all matches. Using `literal` instead of `RegExp contstructor` is preferred, because it's faster.Also if you use RegExp constructor, you additionally need to escape `\` symbols,because slash is special symbol in `string literal`. Consider this:

```
var regliteral = /\./;
//Similar with constructor
var regconstructor = new RegExp('\\.');  //slash is special symbol in string,so we add extra slash before it
```

Comment: @Engineer thanks again for the tip. I will definitely need to spend some dedicated time to learning more about regular expressions.

Comment: I agree but when you need to buid pattern dinamically, it should work, but here even setting global = true, replaces only once. I usally use //g form but I want to build the pattern dinamically now... ?